# Socket operation on non-socket

Tags: c++, linux, socket, redes

Estou apredendo a programar sockets porém estou tendo problemas na hora de realizar a troca de menssagens entre o cliente e o servidor, os dois códigos funcionam como "deveriam" só que o problema está na hora de enviar uma menssagem e receber.

cliente.cpp

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>

struct sockaddr_in server;

#define buffer 200

int main(){

    std::string menssagm;

    int clientfd=(socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP));

    if(clientfd==-1){
        perror("socket");
        std::cout << "Falha\n";
    }else{
        std::cout << "Ok...\n";
    }

    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_port=htons(2000);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    int serverfd=(connect(clientfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)));

    if(serverfd==-1){
        std::cout << "Erro...\n";
        perror("connect");
    }else{
        std::cout << "Conexão estabelecida com sucesso\n";

        if((recv(serverfd,(void*)menssagm.c_str(), buffer, 0)==-1)){
            std::cout << "Erro ao receber menssagem\n";
            perror("recv");
        }else{
            std::cout << "Menssagem recebida\n";
            std::cout << menssagm << "\n";
        }

        if((send(serverfd, "script kiddie", buffer, 0)==-1)){
            std::cout << "Erro ao enviar menssagem\n";
            perror("send");
        }else{
            std::cout << "Menssagem enviada";
        }

    }
}
```

servidor.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct sockaddr_in local;
struct sockaddr_in remoto;

std::string hello="Hello";
std::string word;

int main(){

    int localFd=((socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)));

    local.sin_family=AF_INET;
    local.sin_port=htons(2000);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    bind(localFd,(struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local));

    listen(localFd,1);

    int remotoFd;
    socklen_t len=sizeof(remoto);

    if((remotoFd=accept(localFd, (struct sockaddr*)&remoto, &len))==-1){
        std::cout << "Erro...\n";
    }else{
        std::cout << "Conexão recebida com sucesso\n";
        send(remotoFd, hello.c_str(), 50, 0);
        recv(remotoFd, (void*)word.c_str(), 50, 0);

        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }
}
```

O retorno da função **perror** é:

```
recv(): Socket operation on non-socket
send(): Socket operation on non-socket
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu erro está em achar que `connect()` retorna um descritor. O retorno de `connect()` apenas indica se houve erro (-1) ou sucesso (0).

Logo, as chamadas de `send()` e `recv()` do seu cliente, não utilizam o descritor do servidor.

Outro ponto crucial em seu código está na manipulação dos buffers lidos por `send()` e gravados por `recv()`, você não pode preencher uma `std::string` a partir do ponteiro constante retornado pelo método `c_str()`, ele é qualificado como `const` e seu conteúdo não pode ser modificado dessa forma!

O seu bloco de código que possui a chamada de `accept()` no seu cliente ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if(accept(localFd, (struct sockaddr*)&remoto, &len)==-1)
{
    std::cout << "Erro...\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Conexão recebida com sucesso\n";

    send(localFd, hello.c_str(), hello.length(), 0);

    char buf[50];
    int n = recv(localFd, (void*)buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    buf[n] = '\0';

    std::cout << buf << "\n";
}
```

Segue um exemplo (testado) bem simples de um cliente/servidor utilizando os mesmos conceitos da sua pergunta:

**Cliente:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#define buffer 200

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ){

    struct sockaddr_in srv;

    int s = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

    if( s < 0 ) {
        std::cerr << "[ERRO] socket(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    srv.sin_family = AF_INET;
    srv.sin_port = htons(2000);
    srv.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    std::memset( srv.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(srv.sin_zero) );

    if(connect( s, (struct sockaddr*) &srv, sizeof(srv)) != 0){
        std::cerr << "[ERRO] connect(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "[STATUS] Conexão estabelecida com sucesso..." << std::endl;

    if(send( s, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]), 0 ) < 0){
        std::cerr << "[ERRO] send(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "[STATUS] Mensagem enviada com sucesso!" << std::endl;

    shutdown(s, SHUT_RDWR);
    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

**Servidor:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(void ){

    struct sockaddr_in local;
    char buf[256];

    int s = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );

    if( s < 0 ) {
        std::cerr << "[ERRO] socket(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    local.sin_family = AF_INET;
    local.sin_port = htons(2000);
    local.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    std::memset( local.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(local.sin_zero) );

    if(bind( s,(struct sockaddr*)&local, sizeof(local)) != 0 ) {
        std::cerr << "[ERRO] bind(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if(listen( s, 1 ) != 0){
        std::cerr << "[ERRO] listen(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    while(1)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in remoto;
        socklen_t len = sizeof(remoto);

        std::cout << "[STATUS] Servidor aguardando clientes..." << std::endl;

        int client = accept( s, (struct sockaddr*) &remoto, &len );

        if( client < 0){
            std::cerr << "[ERRO] accept(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << "[STATUS] Nova conexão aceita com sucesso..." << std::endl;

        int n = recv( client, (void*)buf, sizeof(buf), 0 );

        if( n < 0 ){
            std::cerr << "[ERRO] recv(): " << std::strerror(errno) << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        buf[n] = '\0';

        std::cout << "[STATUS] Mensagem recebida (bytes: " << n << "): " << buf << std::endl;

        shutdown( client, SHUT_RDWR );
        close(client);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Teste Cliente:

```
$ ./client "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes."
[STATUS] Conexão estabelecida com sucesso...
[STATUS] Mensagem enviada com sucesso!

$ ./client "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
[STATUS] Conexão estabelecida com sucesso...
[STATUS] Mensagem enviada com sucesso!

./client "O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma."
[STATUS] Conexão estabelecida com sucesso...
[STATUS] Mensagem enviada com sucesso!
```

Teste Servidor:

```
$ ./server
[STATUS] Servidor aguardando clientes...
[STATUS] Nova conexão aceita com sucesso...
[STATUS] Mensagem recebida (bytes: 50): Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.
[STATUS] Servidor aguardando clientes...
[STATUS] Nova conexão aceita com sucesso...
[STATUS] Mensagem recebida (bytes: 43): The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
[STATUS] Servidor aguardando clientes...
[STATUS] Nova conexão aceita com sucesso...
[STATUS] Mensagem recebida (bytes: 35): O rato roeu a roupa do rei de Roma.
[STATUS] Servidor aguardando clientes...
```

Comment: Porque você deu close(...) e shutdown(..) somente no descritor cliente?

Comment: @Khyser: Experimentalmente, o código do servidor está dentro de um loop infinito `while(1){}`. O código do servidor NUNCA vai atingir o `return 0` da `main()`, se houvesse um  `close()` e um `shutdown()` alí, eles também nunca seriam atingidos.

Comment: Qual a diferença entre shutdown e close?

Comment: `shutdown()` altera o estado do `socket`, bloqueando o envio e/ou recebimento de dados em todos os processos que o compartilham, porém, não libera a memória alocada pelo descritor. Já `close()` bloqueia o envio e o recebimento de dados e libera a memoria alocada pelo descritor somente do processo responsavel pela chamada. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160347/close-vs-shutdown-socket